# If $(x_n)$ is a sequence and $l \in \mathbb{R}$ prove $\displaystyle\lim_{y\to\infty}f(y)=l$ iff $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=l$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $(x_n) \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of real numbers and $l \in \mathbb{R}$ 
Define $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, n \mapsto f(n):=x_n$ 
Prove that  $\displaystyle\lim_{y\to\infty}f(y)=l$ iff $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=l$

I have no idea where to begin; I'm not even sure why we can discuss $\displaystyle\lim_{y\to\infty}f(y)$

Comment: We can discuss $lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f(x)$ by taking larger and larger values of $x$ and seeing if $f(x)$ approaching a fixed value $c$ (in this case, $lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f(x)=c$ ), if it goes to infinite, that is, $lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f(x)=\pm \infty$, or if it doesn't have a limit after all (like $lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} sin(x)$.

Comment: $f(x_n)$ dont have sense, the $f$ domain is natural numbers

Comment: @GustavoMarra I'm not sure how that helps?

Comment: @GastónBurrull Sorry, that was misyake on my part, I've edited it now.

Comment: You said "I'm not even sure why we can discuss the limit".

Comment: @Mathlete You are supposed to show that the definition of the limit of a sequence is a special case of the definition of the limit of a function. 'm not sure if that helps you though.

Comment: @GustavoMarra Yes, I meant WHY not how.

Comment: Ok, problem is just a change of name, replace $f(n)$ by $x_n$ (by definition of $f$), there is nothing to prove

Comment: @AlexBecker how would I go about it as a proof?

Comment: @GastónBurrull I don't understand - Why can you do that? What is the significance?

Comment: You defined $f(n)=x_n$ and you want to prove that $\lim f(n)=l$ iff $\lim x_n=l$, just replace

Comment: Are you asking why would one be worried about the behavior of a function when its argument goes to infinity?

Comment: What you have so far is something like _set $x=y$ prove that $x=1$ iff $y=1$_

Comment: @GastónBurrull No I want to prove that $lim f(y) = l$ iff etc etc.

Comment: @leo I don't know how I'd go about writing a proof though.

Comment: Ok $\lim f(y)=\lim f(n)$. Since $n,y\to \infty$, and $y,n\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @GastónBurrull That doesn't seem like a very rigorous proof?

Comment: Yes its rigorous. The name of variable is not important

Comment: maybe it could help to take a look at the definition of a sequence which is exactly a mapping say $g:\mathbb{N}\to X$ for some space $X$ with $i\mapsto g(i)=:g_i$. Hence I would agree that there is nothing to proof since your mapping $f$ is defined by the sequence

Comment: So how would I go about constructing an answer?

Answer (score 3):

First we have,

$$\lim_{y\to \infty} f(y)=\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n)$$

since the name of variable does not change the limit definition (as you can check with $\epsilon$-$\delta$ usual definition). By definition of the function $f$ we have that $f(n)=x_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then $$\lim_{y\to \infty} f(y)=\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n)=\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n$$

finally $$\lim_{y\to \infty} f(y)=l\Leftrightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=l.$$